# Returning a string from a function in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a bit of code that is to make a reference code from a string of a last name. It should take the first `char` whether vowel or not, then search each remaining `char` in the array discarding the vowels storing consonants only in a temp `string`, then return the temp `string` to `string refCode;` The code was given to me in C and I converted it to C++. The code compiles assigns the first value correctly, but if the `if` returns `true` it will fail upon attempting to assign the second value to the temp `string`. The code is over 5 external `.cpp`s and 4 `.h`s so I'll start with the minimal amount and will post more as needed.

Protytpe:

```
string makeRefCode(string lastname, int cNo);
```

Call:

```
refCode = makeRefCode(e[c].lastname, cNo); cout << refCode;//Prints nothing
```

Function Defs:

```
string makeRefCode(string lastname, int cNo)
{
    string tStr;
    unsigned int i, j = 1;
    unsigned int x;
    x = lastname.length();
    tStr[0] = lastname[0];
    cout << tStr[0];//Prints correct value
    for (i = 1; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (!isVowel(toupper(lastname[i])))
        {
            //tStr[j] = lastname[i];//
            j++;
        }
    }
    //refCode[j] = '0'; // add string terminator
    return tStr;
}

bool isVowel(char aChar)
{
    switch (aChar) //<ctype>
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'E': 
        case 'I': 
        case 'O':
        case 'U': return true; break;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

As I've tried resolving this issue I've gotten Assertion, Access violation, and a string error that seems like it's saying the string isn't big enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To add a character to a string, use `push_back`. Don't try to access characters that don't exist. Also, don't add terminators. These are C++ strings, not C-style strings.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that on the null, It was C to begin with.

Comment: On the other hand, `'0'` as a terminator is not usual. If you really did mean `'\0'` (i.e. `0`) however, then follow David's advice.

Comment: Yeah, I went through all that. Originally it was `0`, `'0'` is a product of trying a ton of wrong stuff before resulting to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String don't automatically grow in size. If your string starts at zero length (like `tStr` does) then you need to use `push_back` to add characters to the end of the string.

```
tStr.push_back(lastname[0]);
```

and

```
tStr.push_back(lastname[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great. I've seen `push_back` with `vectors`, but unfortunately I'm a noob, with lots to learn;).

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't say `tStr[0]` on an empty string! Surely, the target string must be big enough to contain the result. Either say `tStr.push_back(lastname[0]);` or `tStr += lastname[0];`, or initialize the string large enough (like with `std::string tStr(lastname.size())`) and then truncate it when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign single characters to a string, make sure that the string has allocated those characters.

The following code is wrong:

```
string tStr;
//...
tStr[0] = lastname[0];
```

Because, it assigns a value to the first character in `tStr`. But `tStr` is empty at this point.

You want to append/push_back the character:

```
string tStr;
//...
tStr.push_back( lastname[0] );
```

Additionally, you should ensure that lastname is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add check for 0 length:

```
if (x==0) ....
```

And you need to replace commmented code `tStr[j] = ...`  with:

```
tStr.push_back(lastname[i]);
```